# converting nand to nor (boolean expression)

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I can make the expression using nand gates but how can I rewrite as products of sum because of making with nor gates.
$$F=S'X+SY$$

I try to take not of not but I can't.

How can I make the circuit *just using nor gates*.

[image]

I get it

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the software that you are showing in the images? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

s'*x+s*y=[s'*x+s*y]''=[(s'x)'(sy)']'=[(x'+s)(s'+y')]'=[x's'+x'y'+ss'+sy']'=
[(x+s)'+(x+y)'+(s'+y)']'= [(x+s)'+(x+y)'+((0+s)'+y)']'= it's-ok :)

Comment: it's the same. (0+s)'=s'. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the DeMorgan's law. (A' + B') = (AB)'. Use it wisely.

Comment: yeah i've mentioned it but i can't do.

Comment: Ok, so it's F = ((S + X')' + (S' + Y')'). If you need only NOR, use another trick. A = (A' + 1')'

Comment: In fact, it works nice without the trick.

Comment: Yeah i've found same result. But, what about $$F = (S'+Y)(S+X)$$ ? isn't it right ? how can I find out the result?

Comment: You don't need it. Cant you see, it was only nor one step before? Nor is (.  + .)'  you had three nors there.

Comment: could i trouble you for drawing?

Comment: No idea how to draw from my phone. Just imagine one nor that gets s' and y, another gets s and x, and the third one gets the outputs of the first two.

Comment: but thats trick? what about not gates?

Comment: you mean s'? just use (s + 0)'

Comment: You should edit the explanation into your answer rather than let this become a long list of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Demorgan Law can be applied in following steps :

```
1) Change all And's to Or's and vice versa. Be sure to give preference to AND while
   conversion when situation in not clear.
```

So F = S'X + SY becomes (S'+ X).(S + Y)

```
2) Next compliment each individual variable or group of variables which you assumed as a 
single entity in step 1.
```

For eg: (A+B)' would be a single entity, so compliment entire 
thing. But A + B' would be 2 entities and you would do A' + B to them.

So F = (S + X').(S' + Y')

```
3) Finally compliment the entire function.
```

So F = [(S + X').(S' + Y')] '

Now in order to implement your function as a POS or SOP, you could use NOR or NAND respectively. Also you can use single input gates (with both inputs shorted) in order to get them to function as a NOT gate.

Comment: I try to make but i have used not gates. How can I get ride of them ? Just using nor gates. http://i.imgur.com/16BtSdN.png

Comment: Man, what's not clear with my answer?

Comment: @AskQuestion.
I think I mentioned it "Also you can use single input gates (with both inputs shorted) in order to get them to function as a NOT gate." So you can use NOR or NAND with both inputs same. They will function as NOT gate.

Comment: could you draw?

Comment: @AskQuestion.The same as top left nor gate in your 2nd image. It is (s + s)' or S' ; clearly it functions as a NOT gate.